# IO does not share in multiple CPU

Tags: linux, kernel, irq, affinity

In my linux server IO doesnot share in multiple CPU.  as below output `ata_piix` intrupts share in only `cpu0`

```
[root@manage ~]# uname -a
```

Linux manage 3.14.24-1smp #12 SMP Tue Mar 17 15:33:27 IST 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

```
[root@manage ~]# cat /proc/interrupts 
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
   0:         72          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    XT-PIC-XT-PIC    timer
   1:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    XT-PIC-XT-PIC    i8042
   2:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    XT-PIC-XT-PIC    cascade
   4:          9          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    XT-PIC-XT-PIC    serial
  **11:    3314260          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    XT-PIC-XT-PIC    ata_piix**
  12:          3          0          0          0          0
```

changed some configuration  now I can change the CPU, but still multiple CPUs are not shared.

```
  **11:    3314260          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       IO-APIC-fasteoi ata_piix**
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run the `irqbalance` daemon to help distribute interrupts across CPU cores.

Comment: [root@manage ~]# echo 03 > /proc/irq/11/smp_affinity
-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error

Comment: I guess this is something with XT-PIC-XT-PIC type